# SQL Server : the multi-part identifier could not be bound Select statement

Tags: sql, inner-join

I saw that there were similar questions, but none of them seemed to help. Can someone please explain what is wrong with this query:

```
SELECT 
    CH.ClaimNumber, CH.ClaimDate, CH.Warehouse, CH.SupplierNumber, 
    CH.SupplierName, CH.ControlAccount, CST.Status,
CD.Line, CD.HasGRN, CD.GRNNumber, CD.ItemCode, CD.ItemDescription, 
    CD.Price, CD.Quantity, CD.CreditValue,
CD.TaxCode, CD.TaxValue, CRS.Description, CD.IssueJournal, CD.CreditNote, 
    CD.SupplierNote, CD.Cancelled
FROM 
    CRClaimHeader AS CH, CRClaimDetail AS CD
INNER JOIN 
    CRStatusTypes AS CST ON CST.StatusID = CH.StatusFK
INNER JOIN 
    CRClaimReasons AS CRS ON CRS.ReasonCode = CD.ReasonCodeFK
WHERE 
     CH.ClaimNumber = @ClaimNumber
```

I get the error on this line:

```
ON CST.StatusID = CH.StatusFK
```

On the `CH.StatusFK`

When I swap what is written in this statement :

```
FROM CRClaimHeader AS CH, CRClaimDetail AS CD
```

And write it like this:

```
FROM CRClaimDetail AS CD, CRClaimHeader AS CH
```

The error shifts to this segment:

```
ON CRS.ReasonCode = CD.ReasonCodeFK
```

On `CD.ReasonCodeFK`

Comment: Aren't you missing a join from ClaimDetail CD to ClaimHeader CH? Instead of the cross join?

Comment: @nonnb Yes, the two tables were not linked. Thanks.

Comment: @nonnb You could list the above as an answer, and I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: Glad you got the issue resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you missing a join from ClaimDetail CD to ClaimHeader CH? Instead of the cross join?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line:

```
FROM CRClaimHeader AS CH, CRClaimDetail AS CD
```

to:

```
FROM CRClaimHeader AS CH
```

and do inner join to CRClaimDetail AS CD Table.

and everything will be o.k.